# Centering website related to content area where content area is smaller than divider divs

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where footer, header and dividers divs throughout the page are wider than the content area div itself.

I am centering website with:

```
.wrap {

width: 1500px;
margin: 0 auto;

}
```

When I resize the window towards the smaller size, the centered view is broken as soon as WIDER footer, header and dividers divs reach left/right side of the screen - http://bit.ly/1nWeHn4.

What I need is for it to only stop when the content area reaches the end of browser screen.

I tried to change the width of wider divs to:

```
max-width: 1500px;
min-width:960px;
```

It kinda fixes the problem and would work fine if my wider divs had solid background, however my divider divs are not. As a result, I can see the divider "moving" while resizing the screen -  http://bit.ly/1vFxAJR

I am sure there is an easy fix,  I just don't know what it is yet :D

Comment: my macbook air screen size cant even see the whole website in order to see what happens :p but i imagine you are not setting %'s on your divs but px's maybe or have min-width set too high

Comment: See, I don't want our Mac friends to feel limited in any way, they already do on daily basis :P

Comment: i guess you have never tried a mac then...

Comment: Lets don't turn it in off top mac/win thread, and no, I did try it plenty

Comment: @emmanuel the content area start to visually move related to divider as soon as 1500px width reached

Comment: @emmanuel this worked! make it an answer and I will accept

Comment: I just changed `repeat` to `no-repeat` in your code to get the exact effect I was looking for in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make **divider** move with the content, you have to set **background-position** to **background** property.

```
.divider { background: url("sprite.png") no-repeat scroll center 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

* changed also **background-repeat** to **no-repeat** as you suggested

Comment: Sorry for late response, you are the best!